# Is there a way to hide only parent element from print?

Tags: html, css

**HTML (example):**

```
<a href="" class="" id="href-test-anchor"><img src="" id="img-test" /></a>
```

So I want  to hide only anchor not img:

```
@media print
{    
    #href-test-anchor
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This code hide and img tag, is there away to do it?

Comment: No, you can't. I would just "re-style" `a` on print.

Comment: @Jax-p What you mean by `re-style` ? The problem is there, that anchor tag is shown only when it's print..

Comment: You could just repeat the image a second time, with a media query that only shows that second image when printing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what does the `<a>` element do on the printed page that you don't want? If it's the underline, or text-decoration then use the `@media print { ... }` to hide that decoration or other styling. Obviously a printed link has no functionality, so what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @kshetline Great man, you should post this as answer :)

Comment: `@media print` + `@media screen` do the magic :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `visibility` instead:

```css
a {
  border:5px solid red; /* You will not see this */
  visibility:hidden;
} 
img {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="" id="href-test-anchor"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/200" id="img-test" /></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

(EDIT: because it got deleted)

Use `visibility` instead.

```
#href-test-anchor 
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#href-test-anchor img
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Doesn't really make sense as to why you are using an anchor, as you are not hyperlinking any text. You could use a div as an alternative; but this does work with an anchor.

Comment: this is not an *edit* but a simple copy/paste of another answer

Comment: you may aswell delete it since its a _copy/paste_.
_you posted a simillar answer seconds after someone else did_ it _MUST_ be a copy paste.